# How to optimize for remote code development?

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssh

I work in a systems company.
So we need to build/test code on a remote server. Generally we do ssh/mosh and develop code there and test. IDE like visual studio + remote SSH works.
Due to network issues, visual studio disconnects and it happens quite often.

Is there a way where i can write code locally on mac and that get synced to remote server immediately and vice versa.. also all git commands should be reflected on the remote end.

I can clone the code base locally, but whenever i need to build i need to push them to the remote server. If there was a way where every file change/git command change is replicated on the other side it would have been better.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Clone the git repo locally?

Comment: You should be able to set up a test environment independent of your production servers, and there should be a deployment process that is the same whether you are deploying to the test or production environment.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to develop / test using a [Docker container](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/), which would represent your server.

That way, you can:

- remain in a local environment for the development
- while testing the deployment of the application as if it was on a server.

Hopefully, the same Docker image, once copied over the remote server, will behave the same way it did when tested on a local server.